# Associated primes of a module and a homomorphism

Tags: commutative-algebra, proof-verification

Let $f: A\rightarrow B$ be a homomorphism of Noetherian rings, and $M$ a $B$-module.

> Question: Is $^af(\operatorname{Ass}_B(M))=\operatorname{Ass}_A(M)$?

If $q$ is an associated prime of the $B$-module $M$, $p=\, ^af(q)$, then from
$A/p\hookrightarrow B/q \hookrightarrow M$, we know $p\in\operatorname{Ass}_A(M)$.

If $p\in\operatorname{Ass}_A(M)$ and $p=\operatorname{ann}(m)$, let $S=A-p$. Since $m/1$ is not zero in $S^{-1}M$, then $\operatorname{ann}(m/1)$ must be contained in an associated prime $S^{-1}q$ of the $S^{-1}B$-module $S^{-1}M$. Then $q\in\operatorname{Ass}_B(M)$ and $^af(q)=p$.

Is the arguments above right?

Comment: Let me mention that it's not necessary to assume $A$ noetherian.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the argument is correct..

Comment: Why is $f^{-1} q \subseteq p$?